# shell script if statement with syntax error causing unexpected end of file

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

the code below, to do mysql dump hourly on my server is causing unexpected end of file error, could someone try to explain what is wrong?

```
mysql_host="localhost"
mysql_database="databasename"
mysql_username="databaseusername"
mysql_password="databasepass"
backup_path=/home/backups
expired=3
today=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
if [ ! -d $backup_path/"$today" ]
then
    mkdir -p $backup_path/$today
else
    /usr/bin/mysqldump -h $mysql_host -u $mysql_username -p$mysql_password $mysql_database > $backup_path/$today/$mysql_database-date"+%H%M".sql
fi
# Remove folder which more than 3 days
find $backup_path -type d -mtime +$expired | xargs rm -Rf
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant `/usr/bin/mysqldump -h $mysql_host -u $mysql_username -p$mysql_password $mysql_database > $backup_path/$today/$mysql_database-$(date +%H%M).sql`?
Also, the first invocation of each day, only the directory will be created and not backup made until the next invocation.

Comment: Checking your script at [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) can help.

Comment: Does the script file have DOS/Windows line endings by any chance? That is, carriage return + linefeed rather than just linefeed? You can check with `cat -vet /path/to/script` -- if the lines end with just "$", it's unix-style (just linefeed), but if they end with "^M$" that's DOS/Windows style and it won't work on unix.

Comment: Thanks guys, I made some adjustments to the code, taking into consideration the points you indicated. And now, the problem is solved. The if statement was really wrong and the file wasn't interpreted by server because it added question mark at end of file name.

Comment: It might be a good idea to enclose the all variable expansions in lines such as `mkdir -p $backup_path/"$today"` inside double quotes: `mkdir -p "$backup_path/$today"` to protect against the day when the names acquire spaces or other special characters.

Comment: Thx for the tip @JonathanLeffler :)